# ftp4j - upload a file in append mode

Tags: ftp, append, ftp4j

Is there a way to upload a file with ftp4j in append mode? I can't find any reference to that in the documentation or on google. Thank you!

Comment: thank you Mark, couldn't add the right tag myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from frp4j 1.6 you can use the append() method:

- append(File)
- append(File, FTPDataTransferListener)
- append(String, InputStream, long, FTPDataTransferListener)

See: http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/api/it/sauronsoftware/ftp4j/FTPClient.html#append%28java.io.File%29

Answer (score 0):

The [FTPClient.upload(File file, long RestartAt)](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/api/it/sauronsoftware/ftp4j/FTPClient.html#upload%28java.io.File,%20long%29) method can restart an upload. The parameter `restartAt` specifies the restart point (number of bytes already uploaded). Use [isResumeSupported()](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/api/it/sauronsoftware/ftp4j/FTPClient.html#isResumeSupported%28%29) to check if the server supports resuming of broken data transfers.

Comment: what we need is something that would append to a file even if the new file is a smaller file. Eventually we changed the way we did this, so, thank you very much anyways :)

Comment: what is the difference between append and upload with restartAt param?

Comment: According to the documentation, append will, well, append the file to an existing remote file. upload with restartAt resumes an upload. So if you call append multiple times, the remote file will repeat the same content multiple times, If you call upload multiple times, you should end up with the same file server-side. I did not test this myself, so *caveat emptor*.